# Dojo expandopane not working

Tags: dojo

I'm currently trying to implement a dojo expandopane in my spring mvc project and it seems to not be working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require('dijit.TitlePane');
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dojox.layout.ExpandoPane");
</script>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar" gutters="true" liveSplitters="true" id="borderContainer">
    <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" maxWidth="225" splitter="true" region="leading" style="width: 225px;">
        Hi. I'm the Expando Pane
    </div>

    <div id="_title_${sec_id}_id" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="center">
        <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_title_${sec_id}_id', widgetType : 'dijit.TitlePane', widgetAttrs : {title: '${sec_title}', open: ${sec_openPane}}})); </script>
        <jsp:doBody />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what i have so far... with this code on the deploy of the project the two div's will not be displayed. Can anyone indicate why is this happening?

I'm not sure if i'm doing anything wrong in the process of getting this expandopane to work.

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect dojo framework on page? Do you enable dojo parser?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
```

Comment: I'm actually using spring mvc..and roo to build the project. there dojo is included... i should have also mention that i have a menubar that is working from dojo... its specific to the exapndopane that i'm have problems. thx

Answer (score 0):

have you forgotten to include parser ?

```
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
```

Comment: the dojo parser is actually being called in another script in the header. I'm not sure if i have to call it back again. Do i really need to do that?

Comment: Please make sure its like this -  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){dojo.parser.parse('parent_dom_node_of_expando_widget')})

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed `dojox.layout.ExpandoPane` doesn't work fine in dojo 1.6. it's weird but I have tried run it several times. The same code with dojo 1.5 work OK.